# WP_Query Not exist and Value in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this query in WP_Query

```
$products = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'starts_with' => $letra,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array( array(
        'key'     => '_stock_status',
        'value'   => 'instock',
        'compare' => '=',
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'pre_orders_enabled',
        'value'   => 'no',
        'compare' => '=',
    ),),
) );
```

This shows me products in preorder with the value "no"

The problem is that I also have products that don't have the "pre_orders_enabled" meta and I need to include them in the WP_Query

In short, I want to display the products that have the value `no` in the meta `pre_orders_enabled` and the products that do not have the meta `pre_orders_enabled`

Answer (score 0):

```
$products = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'starts_with'    => $letra,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
         array(
            'key'     => 'pre_orders_enabled',
             'value'   => 'no',
           'compare' => '=',
         ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'pre_orders_enabled',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
) );
```

Comment: Hello, sorry forgot to put the stock status meta_query update the post could you please update your answer. I'd be really grateful

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
$products = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'starts_with'    => $letra,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'pre_orders_enabled',
            'value'   => 'no',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'     => 'pre_orders_enabled',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'stock_status',
                'value'   => array( 'instock', 'outofstock' ),
                'compare' => 'IN',
            ),
        ),
    ),
) );
```

Comment: Hello, sorry forgot to put the stock status meta_query update the post could you please update your answer. I'd be really grateful

Comment: check my new code

Comment: The code doesn't work :( it stays on infinite load for some reason

Comment: i can update my code plz check again

Comment: It works but it takes too long to show the code and the performance of the server goes up | Edit: Stock doesn't work

Comment: for optimizations you can write a custom SQL query

Comment: I just realized that the stock is not working. Shows products out of stock wrongly :(

Comment: we use a tax_query instead of a meta_query to handle the stock status. We specify the product_visibility taxonomy and exclude the term "outofstock" using the operator parameter set to 'NOT IN'.

Comment: ADD THIS CODE IN PRESENT CODE 
 'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => 'outofstock',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    ),

Answer (score 0):

for optimizations you can write a custom SQL query :

```
global $wpdb;

$sql = $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT DISTINCT ID
    FROM {$wpdb->posts}
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS meta1 ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = meta1.post_id AND meta1.meta_key = 'pre_orders_enabled' AND meta1.meta_value = 'no')
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS meta2 ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = meta2.post_id AND meta2.meta_key = 'stock_status' AND meta2.meta_value IN ('instock', 'outofstock'))
    WHERE {$wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'product'
    AND (
        (meta1.meta_id IS NOT NULL)
        OR (meta1.meta_id IS NULL AND meta2.meta_id IS NOT NULL)
    )
    AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_title LIKE %s",
    $letra . '%'
);

$results = $wpdb->get_col( $sql );
$products = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'post__in'       => $results,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order'          => 'DESC',
) );
```

Comment: It doesn't work for some strange reason it shows me products out of stock wrongly